# What substitution would I make to integrate this?

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Problem:

[image]

The integral is gonna be:

$$\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dy \, dx$$

But I'm quite rusty with my calculus, and this is mainly for a statistics course. I know that $x$ and $y$ are bounded within a unit square region in the $xy$-plane, and I was considering making some sort of $\cos$ or $\sin$ substitution to get rid of that pesky square root, but then I'm not sure what limits to use, and I suspect the $dy dx$ would just become $d\theta d\theta$, which doesn't make sense.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Please try to keep your explanation simple, and don't assume I understand things. It's been a while since my last calculus course :) Thank you!

Comment: $4xy=(2x)(2y)$ and $2x$ is the derivative of $x^2$ and $2y$ is the derivative of $y^2$. Put $z=y^2$. The inner integral (Fubini gets applied first) becomes $2x(x^2+z)^{3/2}|_{z=0}^{z=1}=2x(x^{2}+1)^{3/2}-2x(x^2+0)^{3/2}$. Afterwards put $w=x^2$ in the integral of the first summand.

Comment: @treeleaf I'm not sure what Fubini is, but I think I followed the rest of what you said. So this works because $dz = 2ydy$, so that knocks out the $y$ and the $dy$, and we ignore the $2x$ because we're integrating with respect to $y$. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) is what allows you to turn the double integral in the definition of expected value into the nested integrals in which you integrate first with respect to one variable and then with respect to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
  E(Z) &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} Z f(x,y) \, dx \, dy \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}  4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} 2y \left( \int_{0}^{1}  2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx \right) dy \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} 2y
     \left(
       \int_{0}^{1}  \sqrt{u+y^2} \, du
     \right)
      dy \tag{$u=x^2$} \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} 2y
     \left[
       \frac{2}{3} (u+y^{2})^{3/2}
     \right]_{u=0}^{1} dy \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{4y}{3}
     \left[
       (1+y^{2})^{3/2}-y^{3}
     \right] dy \\
  &= \frac{4}{15}
     \left[
       (1+y^{2})^{5/2}-y^{5}
     \right]_{y=0}^{1} \\
  &= \frac{8}{15}(2\sqrt{2}-1)
\end{align}

Comment: This seems to align with what the other user posted in the comments, and it is quite neat and easy to understand. Thanks for all the effort! This makes sense now. I totally forgot that we don't need to worry about a $y$ when integrating with respect to $x$, and vice versa.

Comment: One minor note: shouldn't it be $y^{\frac{3}{2}$ in the third-to-last step? Since you do the substitution $w = y^2$.

Comment: Verify it by doing backward, i.e. differentiating the anti-derivatives, you'll get back the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^{1}_{0}\int^{1}_{0}4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2} dy \, dx=$$
$$\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\int^{\sec\theta}_{0}4r^4\sin\theta \cos \theta drd\theta+\int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}\int^{cosec \theta}_{0}4r^4\sin\theta \cos \theta drd\theta $$

**Explanation:-**

$$x=r\cos \theta$$
$$y=r\sin \theta$$
$$dxdy=rdrd\theta$$
[image]

$0\leq\theta \leq \pi/4$ and for the variation in $r$,$r:0\to sec \theta(\because x=1$  can be translated as$ r\cos\theta=1)$. Simillarly other region.

Comment: Understood the substitution, but not quite sure I understand the limits.

Comment: You need to get rid of the $dy$ at the end.

Comment: thank you@stuartstevenson

Comment: @AleksandrH I hope substitution is clearer to you.

Comment: I think these calculations are relatively simple. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\iint_{(0,1)^2}4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy&=&\iint_{(0,1)^2}\sqrt{X+Y}\,dX\,dY\\&=&2\iint_{0\leq Y\leq X\leq 1}\sqrt{X+Y}\,dX\,dY\\&=&2\iint_{(0,1)^2}X\sqrt{X}\sqrt{K+1}\,dX\,dK\\&=&2\int_{0}^{1}X\sqrt{X}\,dX\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{K+1}\,dK\end{eqnarray*}$$
by exploting the substitution $x=\sqrt{X}, y=\sqrt{Y}$, then symmetry, then the substitution $Y=KX$, then Fubini's theorem. The last integrals are elementary and they respectively equal $\frac{2}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{3}(2\sqrt{2}-1)$.